# Proper REST Service Structure For A Q&A Service

Tags: rest

I'm creating services that basically issue a set of questions for user authentication (i.e. how old is your pet) and can verify the answers (but must be done within 2 minutes of the questions being presented).  The kicker is the question formulation is a long process so I'd like to have a separate call to get it going async.

...call #1
POST \users{user}\challengerequest -- creates the request, takes a few minutes, and returns request ID

...then polls call #2
GET \users{user}\challengerequest{requestID} -- returns the actual questions, the 2 minute timer starts

...call #3
POST \users{user}\challengeresponse{requestID} -- takes the response, verifies the answers, and returns if things are valid or not.

What I don't like about this currently:
- the first time my GET is called, a timer is kicked off and I believe in theory this is like an update which probably shouldn't be done from a GET
- these feel like transient resources and maybe are not good candidates for a RESTful implementation?

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts on implementation.  What should I reevaluate?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't like about this currently: - the first time my GET is called, a timer is kicked off and I believe in theory this is like an update which probably shouldn't be done from a GET - these feel like transient resources and maybe are not good candidates for a RESTful implementation?

I agree 100%.  [GET should be idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications).  In this case it is not.  I think using a POST to start the questions might be preferred.  This also tells down stream servers to not cache the request.